# update react state using previous data

Tags: reactjs, react-state, use-state

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

I got a React component with a form which can be used to add items or edit a current item. The form is being saved as a state of the component along with all its values.

When submitting the form I'm doing this:

```
const onSubmitForm = () =>
{
      if(editedItem) //the item to edit
      {
        EditSelectedItem();
        setEditedItem(undefined);
      }
      else
      {
        //handle new item addition
      }
      clearFormValues();
      setEditedItem(undefined);
  }
```

And the edit method:

```
const EditSelectedItem = () => 
{
    setItemsList(prevItemsList => 
      {
        return prevItemsList.map(item=> 
          {
            if(item.id !== editedItem.id)
            {
              return item;
            }
            item.name = formSettings["name"].value ?? "";
            item.description = formSettings["description"].value ?? "";
            item.modified = getNowDate();
            return item;
          });
      })
  }
```

The problem is that because the `setItemsList` is not being called synchronously, the `clearFormValues();` in the submit form method is being called before, and I lose the form's old values (in `formSettings`)..

How can I keep the old values of `formSettings` when the `setItemsList` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy here, you can store the formValues in an object before using it an setItemsList

```
const EditSelectedItem = () => 
{

    const values = {
      name: formSettings["name"].value ?? "";      
      description: formSettings["description"].value ?? "";
      modified: getNowDate();
   }
    setItemsList(prevItemsList => 
      {
        return prevItemsList.map(item=> 
          {
            if(item.id !== editedItem.id)
            {
              return item;
            }

            return {...item, ...values};
          });
      })
  }
```

Comment: Interesting, those values should not have been cleared. But I am glad you were able to work around the above solution yourself :-)

Comment: I deleted the comment since what you wrote is correct, but my items here are classes and not just simple objects